# Would adding Parse to an IOS Framework cause issues?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

If I am building a Framework that depends on Parse, would this cause issues for apps already using Parse and would like to use my framework? More specifically, if I initialize my Parse app in the framework, and then the app using this framework initializes Parse again, would they interfere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they will and that's the reason CocoaPods exist, to ease the pain of dependency of frameworks. 
Framework must not depend on another framework is the bottom line. If you do , it will leads to collisions, if the other framework also includes that framework. 
I would suggest you to learn CocoaPods. The dependency problems will find the solution.

Comment: If CocoaPods we're used, would that still allow for essentially two separate Parse apps to be initialized?